# Edit Azure CSS file dynamically?

Tags: azure, storage, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm hosting my website on Windows Azure.

I wanna create a CSS file that the web-master can edit and save onsite.

Is there a simple way to do this without the hassle of blobs?

Comment: Is your application deployed as a cloud service or as a website?

Comment: @GauravMantri website

Comment: With websites you get standard deployment mechanisms like FTP etc. Your web master can download the CSS files and reupload them. Won't that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio online Monaco Editor with AzureWebsite to edit source code - Ref - http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/visual-studio-online-monaco-code-editor.html

Once edit is done you can publish the code to AzureWebsite.

Comment: WOW, never knew about VS online. Anyway, I need an in-site textbox to edit and save CSS.

Comment: AFAIK to the best of my memory, I do not think you have any other option. You might end up creating a page in ASP.Net which would use System.IO.File and read CSS file, then display its content in a textarea. Provide a Save button, and when owner updates the content and clicks save, push the new content to CSS file and write it to disk.

Comment: But can u do it in Azure? I think `System.IO` would fail in Azure, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it will fail if you scale out with multiple instances. But if you are using only one instance then it should be fine.

Comment: It's unlikely that the web-admin will execute same operation twice simultaneously. Anyway I can lock it and make it safe.